# Portable SpringMVC application with MySQL

Tags: mysql, spring-mvc, batch-file, tomcat6

I am trying to run a portable application in Pen drive which contains apache-tomcat-6.0.28, installed MySQL5 server and Jre6. I have a .bat file defined as follows.

```
@Echo Off
 Title Connect To Server
 set ELEARNING_CONFIGS=.
 set JRE_HOME=.\\jre1.6.0_04
set CATALINA_HOME=.\\apache-tomcat-6.0.28\\
cd /d .
 rem echo %OLDDIR%
rem run mysql.bat
cd .\\mysql5

 bin\\mysqld --defaults-file="my.ini"
 ping 1.0.0.0 -n 1 -w 5000 >nul
 bin\\mysqld --defaults-file="my.ini"

cd ..
rem cd .\apache-tomcat-6.0.28\bin
set CLASSPATH=.\\apache-tomcat-6.0.28\\bin\\bootstrap.jar
CALL .\\apache-tomcat-6.0.28\\bin\\startup.bat 
ping 1.0.0.0 -n 1 -w 20000 >nul
START "" "http://localhost/core-web/"
Echo Processing Please Wait......
ping -n 10 127.0.0.1>nul
```

Sometimes this works fine without any issue.
But sometimes i found that we have to run 2 times the batch file to run the application.
And sometimes my application does not start due to "unknown database" error.

Please provide me any pointer to fixed this issue.

Thanks

Shahid

Answer (score 0):

THe thing you are trying is not a usual thing. Can you please let me know exactly why you want web application to be portable?

If it is some demo application or training material etc. that you need to carry always, then I would suggest you to use HSQLDB (or any other java in-memory database) which is simple java api database which doesn't need to be installed, but just jar file is enough. HSQL DB has file based database, so along with jar you can carry disk files & it will work fine anywhere.

As far as I think, MySQL is not something supposed to be portable like that. SO you better go for in-memory or file based database if you really want portable only.

Comment: Thanks Ravi, Yes its big application which contains training material. Due to this and client want to use MySQL.

Comment: Then HSQLDB is best option for you than MySQL.. It is also a database which can be connected through JDBC or hibernate. But it is mainly design for purpose like you. It is just a jar file which you need to put in you project & that jar file itself serves database purpose. It does not need separate installations etc like MySQL. You can do rest all things that you need form database like SQL, procedures, functions etc. So all you need to carry is your war file code & server. Also I think if you go for maven then it has compiler plugins for java so you don't even need to carry jre everywhere.